# curl & mongodb query: How to query for multiple parameters

Tags: bash, mongodb, curl, syntax

I use the following code to login to my dicom server (Orthanc), then query for Series IDs that match the parameters, and write these IDs to a JSON file:

```
curl -u user:password http://localhost:8042/tools/find -d '{"Level":"Series","Query":{"PatientName":"*DGF*", "SeriesDescription":"*Diastolic_TRACE*"}}' > ~/Desktop/updatedSeriesID.json
```

**I would like to save all series IDs that have a "SeriesDescription" of "*Diastolic_TRACE*" OR "*Systolic_TRACE*".**

**How do I query for "*Diastolic_TRACE*" OR "*Systolic_TRACE*"?**

If I repeat the code above but change the "SeriesDescription" and just append to the JSON file using '>>', 2 arrays of IDs are created but I only want 1 array consisting of all the series IDs (for easy indexing).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are more likely to get an anwer if you attract some knowledge about dicom or your orthanc server. I don't see this being a curl or bash issue at all unless you specify the URL that you want to send as single query and help us transform that so curl uses it. But it seems you don't know the form of the URL for a single query, so that's a DICOM or PACS question. imho...

Comment: You were right; this issue has nothing to do with curl or bash - it was an issue to do with Orthanc (an open source DICOM server) and it's limitations on search parameters. Thanks!